# Web Services/Web Mail Networking Logic for Spam Detection

Tags: web-services, security, spam-prevention

I am not sure where is the best place to post this question but I have a serious issue with **ALL** emails sent from my web address being flagged as spam. I know that there are a few engines out there that all email servers use in order to flag an email (from a web server) but does anyone know the details about how they work and how could one exclude their web address from being inappropriately flagged as spam. To provide more context, the CONTENT OF EMAIL is *not* an issue: I can be sending an update, or I can be including or excluding pictures or links – regardless, it is always flagged as spam by Outlook/Hotmail, Gmail, etc.

A stupid question: but I use GoDaddy to host my site, does this impact the chances of being flagged? I am trying to avoid this in the future for future clients.

*Please also do not suggest* that I ask recipients to add me to their Safe Senders list. This is not practical, as we get new users all the time and most are not sophisticated enough to even do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Email providers would ban/flag you based on a whole bunch of criteria that varies widely between domains. Many of them maintain something called sender reputation rating that would categorize **all** your messages as spam from a certain threshold or arbitrary condition forward. Like too many emails being sent to an non-existent mailboxes.

There are some domains that even blacklist your email or (most probably) the IP address you send through, and then they go further - selling/broadcasting this information to other mail servers to "warn" them that you're suspicious.

All that being said is quite difficult to say what is the exact problem in your case without deeper investigation. By the looks of it, probably the GoDaddy IP address/es you use already have some bad reputation accumulated, or the sender email you're using is classified as spam sender based on some automatic rule or users flagging it as such.

This is why Email Validation/Verification services exist. They spare customers from receiving bad reputation, when too many of their emails do not reach a valid email. This is not a trivial task as the environment is ever-changing. One such service is this [one Experian offers](https://www.edq.com/email-verification/). The site has some nice videos and articles to understand the issue at hand. If you are going to be sending large number of emails (especially ones with valid, non-spam content) you'll probably need to resort to such a service eventually.

I hope this helps!